# Axios returning promise not destructed data in react with zustand

Tags: reactjs, promise, axios, react-hooks, zustand

I'm currently trying to get axios running in a react hooks app. The basic get request is working fine and delivering the expected results, but here comes the problem:

I'm using 'zustand' for application state management and established a central backendService.js in which I have declared my async axios function 'getHome()'. The console.log(response.data); prints the expected data.

```
export const [useBackendStore, backendApi] = create((set, get) => ({
 env: environments.local, //is declared above
 home: null,


 getHome: async () => {
  return axios({ method: 'get', url: get().env + '/home/clean' })
  .then(response => {
    set({ home: response.data });
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

},

From another file I now want to call the getHome function and first of all log the results.

```
  const data = backendApi.getState().getHome();
  console.log(data);
```

And now the part I dont understand: The console.log gives me this

```
  Promise {<pending>}
  __proto__: Promise
  [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
  [[PromiseResult]]: Object
```

The PromiseResult has the expected object but i cant figure out how to access it.

I'm pretty new to backend development so please forgive me if I made any obvious mistakes:)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: your API call is asynchronous so that whenever you console it, it will be a promise with state pending. either you can use Async/Await mechanism or can use call back function .then(), .err() to get the response

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya this makes pretty much sense now... Thanks!

Comment: You might find this helpful about [promises and async](https://javascript.info/async).